# add custom fragment inside dialog xml layout and get reference to it

Tags: android, android-fragments

In the app I'm developing I created a custom fragment. I have to place the custom fragment inside a dialog that the user opens by pressing a button. So, in the layout xml of the dialog, I have:

```html
            <fragment android:name="com.XXXX.XXXX.MyCustomFragment"
                android:id="@+id/fragment_id"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

When the user opens the dialog the app needs to initialize the fragment(In the fragment there is a list view) so it needs to get reference to the istance of the fragment. I tryed:

```
MyCustomFragment fragment = (MyCustomFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_id);
```

At runtime the app can't get reference to the fragment so the above code returns a null object. 
How can I get reference to the fragment in this situation?

Comment: Tye with below code :
MyCustomFragment fragment = (MyCustomFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_id);

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work. Maybe because when the activity start it still has no istance of the dialog so when I call  the supportFragmentManager it can't find the fragment.

Comment: Better you use DialogFragmnet instead. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html